# Converting finite state machine diagram into verilog code

Tags: verilog, finite-automata, state-machine

I've been trying to convert this Mealy finite state machine into Verilog code and it never manages to work for all combinations of states/inputs/etc.

[image: fsm]

Here is the Verilog code:

```
 1  `timescale 1ns/100ps
 2  `default_nettype none
 3  
 4  module OddFunction(
 5      output  reg     A,
 6      input   wire    x, y, clk, reset_b
 7  );
 8      
 9      parameter S0 = 1'b0, S1 = 1'b1;
10      
11      reg [1: 0] state, next;
12      initial next = S0;
13      
14      always @(posedge clk) begin
15          if (reset_b == 0) state <= S0;
16          else state <= next;
17          case (state)
18              S0: if ((x || y) && !(x && y)) next = S1; else next = S0;
19              S1: if (!((x || y) && !(x && y))) next = S0; else next = S1;
20          endcase
21          case (state)
22              S0: A = ((x || y) && !(x && y));
23              S1: A = !((x || y) && !(x && y));
24          endcase
25      end
26      
27  endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the minimum change, the logic assignment to `next` should be moved into an separate combinational block (`always @*`). With `next` as combinational, there is not need to give it an initial value. That should give you the behavior you expect.

Also note you have unnecessary logic. `A` and `state` are logically equivalent. Any reasonable synthesizer will merge them. Similarly, you expanded the xor logic into it's equivalent with logic operators. You could simply use the xor bit-wise operator (`^`).

Case statements are common for state-machines. However they are not necessary when the state is encoded with two states. You could simplify and rewrite write the `always` logic as:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  if (reset_b) A <= 0;
  else         A <= A ^ x ^ y;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the circuit and the state diagram you notice that the input to the state machine is a pure EXOR signal. Thus it is simplest to start with:

```
wire my_exor;
   assign my_exor = x ^ y;
```

The next observation is that the output toggles each time the exor is true.

```
always @(posedge clk)
   if (reset)
      A <= 1'b0;
   else if (my_exor)
      A <= ~A;
```

Take the two together and you get Gregs code.